# NSButton binding fails when state is changed programmatically

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsbutton

I have a core data Mac App with different entities and attributes ...
One of these attributes is binded to a NSButton check box ...

Here is my problem : 
If I click with my mouse on the button, i can see its state changing (for the exemple change from un-checked to checked), and the state of the binded attribute is saved to data core because if I close and re-open the app, the button is still checked ...

But ...

If I change the state of this button programmatically, i still can see its state changing (same exemple, change from un-checked to checked), BUT the state of the binded attribute is NOT saved to data core and if I close and re-open the app, the button get back to the un-checked state !

Any ideas ?

### EDIT

Well, I'll try to explain (sorry for my poor english) …

I have to do some operations and verification with some values of this entity called Adherents (for example, if date1> date2 then checkbox1 is checked, and if checkbox2 is checked, checkbox1 is checked no matter of the date compare) …

I first pointed to a solution where I do these operations with the values of this entity, in the "NSManagedObject subclass file Adherents.m

```
- (void)awakeFromFetch{

 [super awakeFromFetch];


    // Controle de la cotisation
    aujourdhui = [NSDate date];
    finCotisation = [NSDate dateWithString:[dateCotisation description]];
    controle = [aujourdhui compare:finCotisation];
   if(controle == NSOrderedAscending)
   {
       self.cotisation = [NSNumber numberWithBool:1];
   }
    else if(controle == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
       if ([self.membreHonneur boolValue] == 0)
       {
            self.cotisation = [NSNumber numberWithBool:0];
        }
      else if ([self.membreHonneur boolValue] == 1)
       {
            self.cotisation = [NSNumber numberWithBool:1];
       }
    }
}
```

Like that, the operation only occurs when the app is launching, that's good but not enough … 
To do that "on the way" (just after the user enter or change the date thru NSDatePicker) the best solution I founded is to check when the date picker are edited by user … 
It seems that I only can do that in the AppDelegate.m file (tried to declare "IBOutlet NSDatePicker *champDate;" in Adherents.h, but then, I was unable to connect the outlet with the checkbox in Interface Builder …), and it seems too that i can't access and manipulate the entity values from there ("self.cotisation" brings an unknown property when used in AppDelegate.m, and I couldn't find how to declare it correctly in AppDelegate.h).

So, my solution is to do these operations in AppDelegate, comparing values of NSDatePicker and acting on NSButton checkbox state …

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [champDate setTarget:self];
    [champDate setAction:@selector(checkDate:)];

}

-(void)checkDate:(id)object {
   finCotisation = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:[champDate stringValue]];
   aujourdhui = [NSDate date];
   NSComparisonResult controle = [aujourdhui compare:finCotisation];
    if(controle == NSOrderedAscending){
        [bouttonCotisation setState:TRUE];
    }
    else if(controle == NSOrderedDescending){
        [bouttonCotisation setState:FALSE];
   }
}
```

But, when acting like that, the binding fails … So, I have to do both : monitoring NSDatePicker and change programmatically checkbox state in my AppDelegate.m AND ALSO checking and changing the entity values with AwakeFromFetch in Adherents.m, I think it's a great nonsense when all is binded ^^

Comment: Why would you change the state of the button? Can you not just change the value of the model attribute that the button represents?

Comment: @Tim : I edited my initial question, couldn't comment here because too long ^^

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the specifics of your problem but gathered this much:

- Seen from outside your data model object has the following properties

  - two date values
  - a boolean value
  - a second boolean value that should have different values depending on the other three values
- you only update the dependent value in the `awakeFromFetch` method, therefore it is not updated when the data is changed during runtime, so you change the checkbox manually in your AppDelegate.

I see two problems with this approach:

1. When using bindings, you should only ever change your model data to update the UI, not call the UI element's setters directly.
2. If you have a property that is fully dependent on other properties don't save it individually (except for caching reasons, but that makes it more complicated). Just compute it on the fly.

I assume your model class looks like this:

```
@interface
@property (strong) NSDate *date1;
@property (strong) NSDate *date2;
@property (assign BOOL someBool;
@end
```

Now we declare add the dependent property in the same way to the header file:

```
// readonly because it cannot be changed directly, only the values it depends on can be changed
@property (assign, readonly) BOOL dependentBool;
```

But for this property we implement the getter in the @implementation ourselves:

```
-(BOOL)dependentBool
{
    if (NSOrderedAscending = [self.date1 compare:self.date2])
        return YES;

    if (self.someBool)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

This way, whenever someone checks the dependentBool property it will return the correct result. You can now bind your checkbox to dependentBool.
But if you change any of the values it depends on the checkbox will not be updated, because it doesn't know that the value changed. To fix this we add the following method to the model class implementation:

```
+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingDependentBool
{
    return [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"date1", @"date2", @"someBool"]];
}
```

This tells anyone observing the `dependentBool` property (as the checkbox will do when bound to this property) that it depends on those keypaths and thus these keypaths should be observed as well.

This way you can just change the value of `date1` for example and any view bound to `dependentBool` will be changed accordingly.

Note: To make this work correctly you must change the values of the properties through their setters (`[myModelObject setDate1:date]` or `myModelObject.date1 = date` or `self.date1 = date`) not change the instance variable directly (`_date1 = date`).

I hope you can adapt this example to your needs.